# How do "Spark Criticals" work?

Tags: brave-frontier

How do Spark Criticals work?

Are they a valuable addition to a nuking team's damage potential?

If I have some bonus to Critical Damage, will this bonus also affect Spark Criticals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark criticals add a chance of increasing the Spark Damage by a specified amount, effectively adding to the Spark Damage modifier whenever they happen.

They are effectively sparks with an added damage.

They are not related with "Critical", and do not receive any bonus from "Crit Damage up", nor do they fill the BB gauge in case of some "BB Gauge boost when Crit" ability.

In FH/FG scenario they aren't really valuable, not adding much when compared to straight-up Spark damage or Critical, but they are rather useful against Crit-resistant or crit-immune bosses.